# getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException error while adding elements to the list using scanner

Tags: java, arrays, list

I am trying to create multiple array list

I need to ask user the number of times he wants to create arraylist

The length of each array list

The elements of each array list

Input example:

2 (which indicates user wants to create 2 list)

3 (which indicates in first list user wants to add 3 items)

1 (1st item to be added in first list)
2 (2nd item to be added in first list)
3 (3rd item to be added in first list)

2 (which indicates in second list user wants to add 2 items)

1 (1st item to be added in first list)
2 (2nd item to be added in first list)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int tcCount = getNoOfTC();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < tcCount; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the size of the array");
            int len = scanner.nextInt();
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                int temp = scanner.nextInt();
                list.get(i).add(temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Enter the below Input and you get the error

Enter the number of Test Cases
3

Enter the size of the array
2

1

Answer (score 2):

This line `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();` creates a variable list but it will be empty.
When you are calling `list.get(i)` on empty list you are getting `IndexOutOfBounds` exception.
To fix this you must fill your list first.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tcCount; i++) {
   list.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

should solve your problem.